# remove last comma from string in while loop in php?

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I am using while loop to get values from my database and my result is like:

[image]

I want to remove comma after last value of loop.

i used code like..

```
<?php
 $cat = get_terms('car_category'); // you can put your custom taxonomy name as place of category.
        foreach ($cat as $catVal) {
            echo '<b>'.$catVal->name.'</b>';
            $postArg = array('post_type'=>'cars','posts_per_page'=>5,'order'=>'desc',
                              'tax_query' => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'car_category',
                                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                                        'terms' => $catVal->term_id
                                                    )
                            ));

            $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
            global $post;

            if($getPost->have_posts()){
                $str = "";
                echo '<div class="yearDiv">';
                    while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
                        $str =rtrim($post->post_title, ",");
                        echo '<span>'.$str.',</span>';
                    endwhile;
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
?>
```

i used rtrim , substr function also for it but comma not removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the post titles in an array and Use Implode instead ..

```
<?php
 $cat = get_terms('car_category'); // you can put your custom taxonomy name as place of category.
        foreach ($cat as $catVal) {
            echo '<b>'.$catVal->name.'</b>';
            $postArg = array('post_type'=>'cars','posts_per_page'=>5,'order'=>'desc',
                              'tax_query' => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'car_category',
                                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                                        'terms' => $catVal->term_id
                                                    )
                            ));

            $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
            global $post;

            if($getPost->have_posts()){
                $str = array();

                    while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
                        $str[] = $post->post_title;

                    endwhile;
            }
            echo '<div class="yearDiv">';
            echo '<span>'.implode(', ', $str).'</span>';
            echo '</div>'
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Utilize rtrim for it. Just make sure at the end of the string space
>   should not be there after comma.

```
   $yourString = rtrim($yourString, ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the rtrim on the while loop but instead after looping you make the rtrim function? Like this:

```
echo '<div class="yearDiv">';
    while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
        $str .= $post->post_title . ",";
    endwhile;
    echo '<span>'.rtrim($str, ",").'</span>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Yes i tried it but it only giving me first value of loop  like..  Aprilia
Dorsoduro 750 ABS,
PRI
PRIMODE,
Yamaha
XS650,
Zero
S,

Comment: Ah yes, you have to use concat for the strings.. glueing all your $post->post_title.. try again this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div class="yearDiv">';
$str = "";
while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
    $str .= $post->post_title.",";
endwhile;
```

try

```
if(substr($str, -1) == ',') {
   $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
}
```

or

```
$str = rtrim($str,",");
```

...

```
echo '<span>'.$str.'</span>';
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Php has a trim function

```
<?php
$str = "item one ,item tow,item three,item 4,";
echo trim($str, ",");
?>
```

the output will be like this

```
item one ,item tow,item three,item 4
```

Comment: No, the output will be like this "item one item tow item three item 4 " because it will remove the comma from every iteration of the loop